# Javascript stringify '%%' loses a percent sign

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

Why is the output of stringify missing a percent sign?

```
var a = ["dp",'%%'];
var t = JSON.stringify (a);
console.log ('t: ' + t);
```

Result is:

```
t: ["dp","%"]
```

Why isn't the result:

```
t: ["dp","%%"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I ran the exact code you posted and got the latter result.

Comment: I ran it with node.js v0.10.36

Comment: Interesting.  I just ran with JSBin and got the latter result too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As specified in the documentation for [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) in Node.js, the function takes arguments in a [printf-like way](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format):

> The first argument is a string that contains zero or more placeholders.
>   Each placeholder is replaced with the converted value from its corresponding argument. Supported placeholders are:
>
> %s - String.
>   %d - Number (both integer and float).
>   %j - JSON. Replaced with the string '[Circular]' if the argument contains circular references.
>   %% - single percent sign ('%'). This does not consume an argument.
>   If the placeholder does not have a corresponding argument, the placeholder is not replaced.

Thus, any occurrence of `%%` in a string printed with `console.log` *in Node.js* (not browser) will be replaced by a single `%`. Any `%s`, `%d` or `%j` will be replaced by a string, number or JSON string, respectively. Here are some examples:

```
console.log("This is a string: %s", "Hello, World!");
//= This is a string: Hello, World!

console.log("This is a number: %d", 3.14);
//= This is a number: 3.14

console.log("This is a JSON string: %j", { value: true });
//= This is a JSON string: {"value":true}

console.log("This is a single percentage sign: %%");
//= This is a single percentage sign: %

console.log("If we use %%s and %%d here we get '%s' and '%d'.", "a string", 100);
//= If we use %s and %d here we get 'a string' and '100'.
```

Calling `console.log` in a browser, however, will just print the plain string with none of the above substitutions.

Comment: @Frxstream do you know why would in this case: 1. if you console.log right away after setting data variable, then two of the %% are missing
2. but if you paste the variable definition in the console first and then after that paste just console.log(data), the %%%% will be there

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286386/special-characters-string-not-properly-processing-in-js#72286386

Comment: "_in Node.js (not browser)_" - The same happens in the browser console. (At least at this point in time, for Google Chrome.)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have anything to do with the `JSON.stringify`. I can reproduce the single `%` output with `node 0.10.36` by just doing `console.log('%%')`. This is likely an issue with `util.format` used internally for `console.log` by node.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/util.html#util_util_format_format

However, in `node 4.0` I get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Just upgraded to node 4.2.1 and also now get the %%, as desired.